# Can I loop over file names that differ only by an integer number?

Tags: c++, for-loop

I have 100 files called "realization_i.dat", where i is an integer from 0 to 99.

I want to loop over each file in order to import the data for use in manipulation in my code.

I'm unsure on how to do this, but this is what I have so far:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++) {

    string path = "/Users/Olly/Documents/BScProject/WeakLensing/SIGNAL/";
    string mainFile = path + "realization_" << i << ".dat";
    vector <double> Pos1, Pos2, E1, E2, Z, W, SC;
    ifstream in(mainFile.c_str(), ios::in);
```

My thoughts are that, for i = 0, I would be inputting the data from the realization_0.dat file, and then realization_1.dat file, etc. up to realization_99.dat.

I am getting the following error:

```
ShearStacks.cpp:41:49: error: invalid operands to binary expression
      ('std::__1::basic_string<char>' and 'int')
        string mainFile = path + "realization_" << i << ".dat";
```

Can anyone explain why this doesn't work and suggest a new way of looping over the files? (Quite new to C++.)

Comment: Why *would* "realization_" << i << ".dat" work?

Comment: I thought it might work in the same way that if you do cout << "realization_" <<  0 << ".dat" you get realization_0.dat. There is a nice explanation below as to why that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), the `+` operation will happen first. `(path + "realization_") << i << ".dat";` then the compiler will attempt to look for a suitable operator `<<` between the resulting `std::string` and an `int` which isn't available, then it chokes.

You probably want to use [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) to convert your numbers to string:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

    string path = "/Users/Olly/Documents/BScProject/WeakLensing/SIGNAL/";

    string mainFile = path + "realization_" + std::to_string(i) + ".dat";

    vector <double> Pos1, Pos2, E1, E2, Z, W, SC;
    ifstream in(mainFile.c_str(), ios::in);
    ......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A string is not a stream!

Use normal string-concatenation:

```
 string mainFile = path + "realization_" + std::to_string(i) + ".dat";
```

Note that `to_string` is only available starting with C++11.

Answer (score 0):

The string 'mainFile' can not used that way.

I would suggest using a std::stringstream :

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << "/Users/Olly/Documents/BScProject/WeakLensing/SIGNAL/"
   << "realization_" << i << ".dat";

std::string mainFile = ss.str();
```